# Debugging exceptions in DOM Promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, exception, error-handling, promise

Not long ago Chrome DevTools started supporting async stack traces (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/async-call-stack/) so now we can avoid pain of debugging asynchronous code.

But also DOM Promises (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) were released, successfully bringing pain right back.

If any exception was thrown somewhere inside promised code it would be swallowed by promises system and would not let debugger stop even if "Pause on exceptions" is on.

Alright, we can turn on "Pause on caught exceptions" but that will lead to pause on every promise rejection what usually is redundant. I only want to catch kinds of real JavaScript or libraries errors showing that my code is written incorrectly. Promises may be rejected without logic error though:

```
function showLargeImage (user) {
    return Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (!user.image.large) {
            // Expected behavior. No exception pause needed.
            reject('No larger image.');
        } else {
            // What if element doesn't exist? We want to catch exception here.
            $('#user-' + user.id + '-large-image')[0].style.display = 'block';
            resolve();
        }
    });
}
```

Has anyone faced same issue? How to debug that code?

**UPDATE**: Code example was wrong. Exceptions are swallowed only in "then" handler (not in promise body). Should look like:

```
function showLargeImage (user) {
    return loadLargeImage(user).then(function (largeImage) {
        if (!largeImage) {
            // Expected behavior. No exception pause needed.
            return Promise.reject('No larger image.');
        } else {
            // What if element doesn't exist? We want to catch DOM exception here.
            $('#user-' + user.id + '-large-image')[0].src = largeImage;
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Define "written incorrectly". You don't mean syntax errors, do you?

Comment: my guess: use try catch around the critical parts and reject with the error message?

Comment: @MaxArt, I don't. I mean logic errors like that in example above.

Comment: @bbuecherl what is the difference? I can evaluate code that will cause exception, I can throw my own exception or I can reject promise. The problem is it's all the same. It will result in rejected promise with caught exception and no pause in debugger.

Comment: Granted I'm using Chrome 37 dev and not 35, but it *does* stop on exceptions inside the handler, without the need to check "Pause On Caught Exceptions". Example: `new Promise(function(ok) {ok(null.a);});` If it's not the behavior you're getting, I guess it has been some minor bug that got fixed later.

Comment: ES6 promises are not usable in application code, try promise libraries with better error handling and debugging utilities like bluebird or when.js

Comment: Any progress on your problem?

Comment: @MaxArt (and all) I was wrong in my example. Exeptions from within Promise resolver are thrown. Those from within "then" callback are not.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I did not find any solution as libraries like Q and Vow provide same functionality. They swallow exceptions thrown in "then". So I wrote my own wrapper for Vow library that re-throws special types of errors. For example if promise was rejected with instance of Error it would be re-thrown (the same way as if done() was called).

Comment: Ah, ok - for the record, Bluebird does not swallow these exceptions and neither does `when`, your solution sounds similar (but not the same) to what Angular does with $q.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum It's sad, that the whole situation is unclear, there is no strong recomendation or standard from guys from W3C.

Comment: @Ajaxy any progress?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum nope.

Comment: @Ajaxy did you stick to native promises?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I ended up using my fork of https://github.com/dfilatov/vow .

Answer (score 5):

Simple workaround - **avoid DOM promises**. They are not production ready *yet*.

This is a known issue. DOM promises at the moment are rather experimental:

- They are much slower than fast promise implementations like Bluebird.
- They provide no `.done` method or unhandled rejection detection in Chrome. Exceptions will be swallowed silently.
- They provide a very limited subset of the functionality.

If you *have* to use DOM promises, use Firefox, version 27+ features unhandled rejection detection based on GC. The stack traces are still a lot worse than Bluebird's but at least it'll not swallow the exceptions silently.

The upside is that there are plans to build better unhandled rejection detection into Chrome DOM promises.

You can use Bluebird and swap it out for native promises in production (although it outperforms them and you *really* want good debuggability in production).

#### But what do I do about my current code?

Most promise libraries, like Bluebird can act as a drop-in replacement.

Comment: Is this still relevant in July 2016?